# Time Complexity (Big O Notation)

Tags: qiskit, complexity-theory, ibm-quantum-devices, error-mitigation

What is the time complexity of the two error-mitigation methods that are implemented in [qiskit.ignis](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/measurement-error-mitigation.html#Error-mitigation-in-Qiskit).

1- pseudo inverse.
2- least squares.

Comment: you might want to take a look to https://learn.qiskit.org/course/quantum-hardware/measurement-error-mitigation . This new version of the textbook does not use the unmaintained Ignis.